# JavaScript does not work after outsourcing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I'm using the Multi Page Template (all pages and javascriot in one html file).  I just restructure my jQuery mobile app:

- Before: all JavaSripts in the html file, example: 
  `<div data-role="page>.....<script></script> </div>`

  - Now: all JavaScripts are outsourced in a own file. But now comes the **problem**:

I'm searching after addresses at one page. Each result is stored in a history (localStorage). So the user can use the search or click on old history search results.

Since I outsourced the script for this page, the history doesn't work. I will show you the working code and the not working code:

**Working code - pre outsourced:** 
This code works. JavaScript is in page div:

```
<div data-role="page" id="searchPage" class="bg-light">

    <div data-role="content">

        <div id="content-search">
            <p><input type="text" name="address" id="address" class="stored" value="" /></p>
            <p><input type="submit" id="submitAddress" value="Search" data-theme="a" data-corners="false" /></p>
        </div>

        <div id="searchHistory">
            <div class="ui-corner-all custom-corners">
                <div class="ui-bar ui-bar-c">
                    <h3>History:</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="ui-body ui-body-c">
                    <div id="lastResults" class="ui-body ui-body-c ui-corner-all"></div>
                </div>
            </div>  
        </div>  

    </div>

    <script>
    ......
    // check and show previous results in **lastResults** div
    if (localStorage.getItem("history") != null) {
        var historyTemp = localStorage.getItem("history");
        var oldhistoryarray = historyTemp.split("|");

        oldhistoryarray.reverse();

        $("#lastResults").empty();
        jQuery.each( oldhistoryarray, function( i, val ) {
            $("#lastResults").append(
                "<ul data-role=\"listview\" data-inset=\"true\" >" +
                    // store history in localStorage
                    "<li><a href=\"#mapPage\" onClick=\"getHistory("+i+");\" >"+oldhistoryarray[i]+"</a></li>" +
                "</ul>"
            );
            // max. history
            if (i==3) {
                return false;
            }
        });


    } else {
        // hide search history
        console.log("no history");
        $("#searchHistory").hide();
    }

    function getHistory(i){
        localStorage.setItem('address', oldhistoryarray[i]); 
    }

    </script>

</div>
```

**Not Working code - JS outsourced in own file:**
JavaScript is now in own file (function.js):
**index.html:**
detail code see above

```
<div data-role="page" id="searchPage" class="bg-light">

    <div data-role="content">

    </div>

    <script></script>

</div>
```

**function.js:**

```
// check and show previous results in **lastResults** div
if (localStorage.getItem("history") != null) {
    var historyTemp = localStorage.getItem("history");
    var oldhistoryarray = historyTemp.split("|");

    oldhistoryarray.reverse();

    $("#lastResults").empty();
    jQuery.each( oldhistoryarray, function( i, val ) {
        $("#lastResults").append(
            "<ul data-role=\"listview\" data-inset=\"true\" >" +
                // store history in localStorage
                "<li><a href=\"#mapPage\" onClick=\"getHistory("+i+");\" >"+oldhistoryarray[i]+"</a></li>" +
            "</ul>"
        );
        // max. history
        if (i==3) {
            return false;
        }
    });


} else {
    // hide search history
    console.log("no history");
    $("#searchHistory").hide();
}

function getHistory(i){
    localStorage.setItem('address', oldhistoryarray[i]); 
}
```

Comment: I don't think 'outsourcing' means what you think it means.

Comment: Where have you included the `function.js` file?

Comment: you have to wrap code in `$(document).on("pageinit", function` or any page event.

Comment: I've tried to wrap my code in a page event like yours or pagecreate, pageshow..., but if I do that, I get this error: getHistory is not defined ... and if the function getHistory is not in $(document).on("pageinit",.. I get this error: oldhistoryarray is not defined

Comment: I think the sequence of executing is the problem. If the function getHistory is NOT in the  `$(document).on("pagecreate", "#searchPage",function(){ ... ` - it will executed first and oldhistoryarray is not defined, because oldhistoryarray is defined in the `$(document).on("pagecreate", "#searchPage",function(){ ... `.

If the function getHistory is IN the `$(document).on("pagecreate", "#searchPage",function(){ ... ` - it will not even run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are not executing your script after the page has finished loading, there's a chance queries like `$("#searchHistory")` might be returning empty.

Make sure you execute your script in a callback that is called at the onload event.

so I'd suggest something like this (please also check that you initialize your "history")

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.js"></script>

<script src="function.js"></script>

<script>

$(document).on( "pagecreate", function( event ) {
  console.log("page created")


    $('#submitAddress').on('click',function(){
        makeHistory();
    })

});

</script>
</head>

<body>
<div data-role="page" id="searchPage" class="bg-light">

    <div data-role="content">

        <div id="content-search">
            <p><input type="text" name="address" id="address" class="stored" value="" /></p>
            <p><input type="submit" id="submitAddress" value="Search" data-theme="a" data-corners="false" /></p>
        </div>

        <div id="searchHistory">
            <div class="ui-corner-all custom-corners">
                <div class="ui-bar ui-bar-c">
                    <h3>History:</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="ui-body ui-body-c">
                    <div id="lastResults" class="ui-body ui-body-c ui-corner-all"></div>
                </div>
            </div>  
        </div>  

    </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

`function.js` then would be

```
// check and show previous results in **lastResults** div

function makeHistory()
{
if (localStorage.getItem("history") != null) {
    var historyTemp = localStorage.getItem("history");
    var oldhistoryarray = historyTemp.split("|");

    oldhistoryarray.reverse();

    $("#lastResults").empty();
    jQuery.each( oldhistoryarray, function( i, val ) {
        $("#lastResults").append(
            "<ul data-role=\"listview\" data-inset=\"true\" >" +
                // store history in localStorage
                "<li><a href=\"#mapPage\" onClick=\"getHistory("+i+");\" >"+oldhistoryarray[i]+"</a></li>" +
            "</ul>"
        );
        // max. history
        if (i==3) {
            return false;
        }
    });


} else {
    // hide search history
    console.log("no history");
    //and you probably need to initialize your history here, something like
    localStorage.setItem("history", "lalala");
    $("#searchHistory").hide();
}

}

function getHistory(i){
    localStorage.setItem('address', oldhistoryarray[i]); 
}
```

Now the pagecreate event also binds a behaviour to your search button to actually update the history each time it is clicked.

Comment: I think your answer mean the same as my comment 3 minutes ago, right? But I found no solution till now

Comment: part of your problem is that your `if` statement in `function.js` is executed the moment the script is loaded. This means that `$('#lastresults')`will be seeking for  an id that is not yet part of the DOM tree. Wrap your `if` into a function and call this at the onload event, or since you are using jquery mobile, at pagecreate.

Comment: please check the updated answer and let me know if it sheds more light into your problem

Comment: I see the problem, but I can't use your solution ,because there is much other code and dependencies. I will try it next days. Thank you

Comment: sure. let me know if you need more assistance, and please accept the answer if it helped